# Difference between three dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

in one example, I saw three dependencies block in `build.gradle`. 
example:
root folder: `build.gradle`
1.

```
buildscript{
 dependencies{
 }
}
```

2.Under android block

```
android{
 dependencies{
 }
}
```

3. I see one more dependencies block on root folder

   `buildscript{
    }
    dependencies{
    }
     android{
    }`

First two are been explained in Android developer site. 
1st: is applicable for complete project
2nd: per module.

I am not understanding what 3rd dependency block means.

Comment: The third point isn't organized in a code format can you fix it. Since I don't seem to find such a block.

Comment: Please share the screenshot? @Aada

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing because Android Studio by default shows both `build.gradle` files right next to each other (when using the Android view).

[image]

If you switch to the Project view you can see the actual structure and where the different `build.gradle` files are located.

[image]

The `build.gradle` (Project: MyApplication) file is in the root folder of the project and its configuration settings apply to every module in the project. A module is an isolated piece of the bigger project. In a multi-module project, these modules have their own jobs but work together to form the whole project. Most Android projects only have one module, the app module.

The `build.gradle` (Module: app) file here is in the `app` folder. Its build settings apply only to the app module. If there were another module, then the it would have its own `build.gradle` file, too. As an [example](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library), I made a library project with three modules: a library module, a demo app module, and another app module that I plan to use for testing. Each of them have their own `build.gradle` files that I can tweak.

[image]

In a basic project, almost everything you need to edit will be in the app module's `build.gradle` file. You can remember it like this:

> **You're making an *app*, so go to the `build.gradle` (Module: *app*) file.**

## Further reading

- [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) (Android documentation--very readable and useful)
- [Introduction to multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html) (Gradle documentation)

Answer (score 0):

> First two are been explained in Android developer site. 1st: is applicable for complete project 2nd: per module.

It is not exact.

The `buildscript` block can be specified in the root level but also in the module `build.gradle` file.
These `dependencies` block only controls the dependencies for the buildscript process itself, not for the application code.

> 2.Under android block

```
android{
 dependencies{
 }
}
```

It **is not** correct.
The correct syntax is:

```
android {
  ...
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Don't put these dependencies in the top-level file.